# Why didn't my Scheduled Reminder send?

Tags: scheduled-reminders

My scheduled reminders aren't working.  What are some causes?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of reasons Scheduled Reminders might not be working.  It's important to first distinguish between "No Scheduled Reminders are working" and "A particular scheduled reminder isn't working".

#### No scheduled reminders are working

- You haven't yet set up your cron job.
- Your Scheduled Reminders Scheduled Job (**Administer menu » System Settings » Scheduled Jobs**) isn't enabled.
- Your outbound email settings aren't configured correctly.  Test them at **Administer menu » System Settings » Outbound Email**.

#### One scheduled reminder isn't working

- Your "Effective Start Date" or "Effective End Date" are outside the range of the reminder.
- This reminder has already been sent.  E.g.:

  - You have a reminder to go out 7 days before an event, which sends successfully.
  - 3 days before the event, you postpone the event to next month.
  - 7 days before the event, the same scheduled reminder will NOT fire again, because Civi won't send the same reminder twice, and the participants already received the reminder.
- Your reminder is set to go to Additional Recipients, and is an event reminder.  This doesn't work, and is removed in current versions of Civi.

#### Other things to check

- Check the Scheduled Job log for Scheduled Reminders to make sure you see both the "job is starting" and "job finished successfully" messages.
- Check your mail logs to ensure that the mailing actually went out.  Some third-party mailers (e.g. SendGrid, Sparkpost) won't let you send with any "From" address you like, and your mail logs will indicate that the message was rejected by your mailing service.